# How to access folders inside public_html from user directory in URL

Tags: apache, unix, subdirectory, public-html

I have a user directory on a domain such as www.something.com/~user/

and I want to be able to both create and access a folder like www.something.com/~user/folder/

In UNIX I can make a directory inside the public_html folder, but I'm currently unable to access it through the URL. I am using an Apache web server. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What error you are encountering with , Is it 404 ?

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/public_html.html answers your question.
Once you've created $HOME/public_html/my/folder and configured your apache webserver appropriately (don't forget to restart it) you will be able to browse to

http://www.something.com/~username/my/folder